# error in declaring const variable in php vs define

Tags: php, constants

> As you can see here, phpStorm is showing error on declaring const root saying: **expression is not allowed as const value**, but it works fin when **define** used.

```
const ROOT = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
define('ROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));
```

[image]

Comment: Then use `define`

Comment: *As you can see here*, sorry but I can't? The only thing I see is two lines of code.

Comment: @Loek I hope, now you can see.